# is jquery 1.12.3 contain jquery UI for autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I install  jquery 1.12.3 and add it to my project ... I want to use autocomplete on textarea with jquery UI for example :

```
var appendTo = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", "#someElem" );
```

... so my question is : 
Does jquery 1.12.3 contain jquery UI for autocomplete or must I download another version of jquery UI to use autocomplete on textarea? if I must to download another jquery UI  How to do it ?

Comment: Note that jQuery and jQuery UI are two different libraries, and the version numbers are not the same. jQuery UI needs jQuery (it's a collection of plugins and other enhancements).

Answer (score 0):

According to the API the Autocomplete widget was added in Version 1.8

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Instructions for adding UI to project here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui

Comment: That's the jQuery UI version, not a jQuery version.

Comment: @Barmar The question asks if jQuery contains jQuery UI. It does not - you need a separate import in addition to the mandatory jQuery import.

Comment: The answer to that question is no. jQuery doesn't contain jQuery UI.

Comment: so I can use jquery ui 1.12.1 with jquery 1.12.3 in the same project is it true ?@Barmar